# Finding the proper operator in RXJS to map/reduce over inner entries of an Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

Problem: 
Look at my 3 `console.log` and the Output image. Next the `tap` operator is not logging each entry because the output from the previous operation: `mergeMap(getDataByUrl)` output looks like `Observable<entry[]>`.  I think it could work if each entry was an observable like: `Observable<Observable<entry>[]>`.  I've added a `tap` operator where I'm doing the expected transformation; however, it's not really working via subscription and two I was wondering if there were better operators.

Question:
Is there a proper operator to map/reduce over the inner entries returned by this mergeMap? Or just how can I make my `subscribe` log out the proper output?

```
this.router$ = this.router.events.pipe(
  find(nextRoute),
  pluck('url'),
  mergeMap(getDataByUrl),
  tap(i => {
    console.log(i); // Wrong output (app.component.ts:52)
    const output = i.map(i => i[ 'data' ])
                    .reduce((acc, val) => {
                      acc[ val.id ] = val;
                      return acc;
                    }, {});
    console.log(output); // Proper output (app.component.ts:58)
    return output;
  }),
);
this.router$.subscribe(console.log); // Wrong output (Subscriber.js:196)
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: It depends on what exactly is returned by the getDataByUrl method - so we especially need to know on what is in the data object. Also are you aware that the find operator will kill your stream once it emit's once - so this will not be called again when the route hits again. One tip if you want to have better and faster answer: make a small example app on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `reduce` operator provided by Rx, you can happily replace `tap` operation with `from` and `reduce` and it should work. Whatever you return from `tap` doesn't pass down the chain, it is a side effect operator, mainly used for debugging or modify global value.

```
this.router$ = this.router.events.pipe(
  find(nextRoute),
  pluck('url'),
  mergeMap(getDataByUrl),
  switchMap(i => from(i).pipe(map(i=>i.data))),
  reduce((acc, val) => {
                      acc[ val.id ] = val;
                      return acc;
                    }, {})
);
```